# i'm not able to solve the dart sdk environment

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, splash-screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBZtf.png)

to solve the version requirements.
Because dev depends on splashscreen ^2.12.10 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.5.

Because dev depends on splashscreen any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.20.1 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.

Comment: Change it to `sdk: '>=2.9.0 <4.0.0'` as your current version(`3.1.5`) installed is higher than `3.0.0`

Comment: yes bruh i have changed the comment but even though its showing me the same mistake. Could you give me ur watsapp number so that i could connect uh so u can able to help me out.!!! please.

Comment: Oh sorry you can't use [SplashScreen](https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen) package now as it does not support null safety. You can use it if you downgrade you flutter version before null safety got enabled. But No body would recommend that. You can try using [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Comment: Try This. Maybe it work for you => sdk: '>=2.10.0 <4.0.0'

Comment: Because dev depends on environment from sdk which doesn't exist (unknown SDK ">=2.10.0 <4.0.0"), version solving failed.
not working brooo.